# how to create dynamic rows of records for creating xls file using list

Tags: java, poi-hssf

Here after fetching records from database I have added data in some list and I have set some session variables for them so that I can access in another method by using get(key) method of session which I am successful to do so .Now what I want is I want to create dynamic records by setting this list value in row but I am unable to do so.It creates file but there is no record displayed .Below is my code:

```
package com.ca.actions;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import com.ca.database.Database;
import com.ca.pojo.Event;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;

public class DataForGeneralReportsAction extends ActionSupport implements
        Preparable, SessionAware {
    private List<String> eventsGeneral = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> companiesGeneral = new ArrayList<String>();
    private SessionMap<String, Object> sessionMapGeneral;
    List<String> eventIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> eventNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> eventVenueList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> eventTimeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> companyNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> totalAmountList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> receivedAmountList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> balanceAmountList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> eventTdsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> paymentDateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> chequeDdList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String eventGeneral = null;
    private String companyGeneral = null;
    List<Event> dataForGeneralReports;

    public List<String> getEventIdList() {
        return eventIdList;
    }

    public void setEventIdList(List<String> eventIdList) {
        this.eventIdList = eventIdList;
    }

    public List<String> getEventNameList() {
        return eventNameList;
    }

    public void setEventNameList(List<String> eventNameList) {
        this.eventNameList = eventNameList;
    }

    public List<String> getEventVenueList() {
        return eventVenueList;
    }

    public void setEventVenueList(List<String> eventVenueList) {
        this.eventVenueList = eventVenueList;
    }

    public List<String> getEventTimeList() {
        return eventTimeList;
    }

    public void setEventTimeList(List<String> eventTimeList) {
        this.eventTimeList = eventTimeList;
    }

    public List<String> getCompanyNameList() {
        return companyNameList;
    }

    public void setCompanyNameList(List<String> companyNameList) {
        this.companyNameList = companyNameList;
    }

    public List<String> getTotalAmountList() {
        return totalAmountList;
    }

    public void setTotalAmountList(List<String> totalAmountList) {
        this.totalAmountList = totalAmountList;
    }

    public List<String> getReceivedAmountList() {
        return receivedAmountList;
    }

    public void setReceivedAmountList(List<String> receivedAmountList) {
        this.receivedAmountList = receivedAmountList;
    }

    public List<String> getBalanceAmountList() {
        return balanceAmountList;
    }

    public void setBalanceAmountList(List<String> balanceAmountList) {
        this.balanceAmountList = balanceAmountList;
    }

    public List<String> getEventTdsList() {
        return eventTdsList;
    }

    public void setEventTdsList(List<String> eventTdsList) {
        this.eventTdsList = eventTdsList;
    }

    public List<String> getPaymentDateList() {
        return paymentDateList;
    }

    public void setPaymentDateList(List<String> paymentDateList) {
        this.paymentDateList = paymentDateList;
    }

    public List<String> getChequeDdList() {
        return chequeDdList;
    }

    public void setChequeDdList(List<String> chequeDdList) {
        this.chequeDdList = chequeDdList;
    }

    public SessionMap<String, Object> getSessionMapGeneral() {
        return sessionMapGeneral;
    }

    public void setSessionMapGeneral(
            SessionMap<String, Object> sessionMapGeneral) {
        this.sessionMapGeneral = sessionMapGeneral;
    }

    public String getEventGeneral() {
        return eventGeneral;
    }

    public void setEventGeneral(String eventGeneral) {
        this.eventGeneral = eventGeneral;
    }

    public String getCompanyGeneral() {
        return companyGeneral;
    }

    public void setCompanyGeneral(String companyGeneral) {
        this.companyGeneral = companyGeneral;
    }

    public List<Event> getDataForGeneralReports() {
        return dataForGeneralReports;
    }

    public void setDataForGeneralReports(List<Event> dataForGeneralReports) {
        this.dataForGeneralReports = dataForGeneralReports;
    }

    public List<String> getEventsGeneral() {
        return eventsGeneral;
    }

    public void setEventsGeneral(List<String> eventsGeneral) {
        this.eventsGeneral = eventsGeneral;
    }

    public List<String> getCompaniesGeneral() {
        return companiesGeneral;
    }

    public void setCompaniesGeneral(List<String> companiesGeneral) {
        this.companiesGeneral = companiesGeneral;
    }

    public DataForGeneralReportsAction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = new Database().Get_Connection();

            // load companies
            PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT company_name FROM event");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                companiesGeneral.add(rs.getString("company_name"));
            }

            // load events
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT event_name FROM event");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                eventsGeneral.add(rs.getString("event_name"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = new Database().Get_Connection();

            // load the table. The first time the table is loaded completely
            String sql = "SELECT EVENT_ID, EVENT_NAME, COMPANY_NAME,EVENT_VENUE,TOTAL_AMOUNT,RECEIVED_AMOUNT,EVENT_TDS,BALANCE_AMOUNT,CHEQUE_DD_NO,"
                    + "date_format(PAYMENT_DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') as dateAsPayment,EVENT_TIME "
                    + "FROM event";
            String where = "";

            // if instead this action has been called from the JSP page,
            // the result is filtered on event and company:
            if (eventGeneral != null && companyGeneral != null) {
                where = " WHERE event_name = ? AND company_name = ?";
            }

            // load companies
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql + where);
            if (where.length() > 0) {
                ps.setString(1, eventGeneral);
                ps.setString(2, companyGeneral);
            }
            dataForGeneralReports = new ArrayList<Event>();
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            int i, j = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {

                dataForGeneralReports.add(new Event(rs.getString("EVENT_ID"),
                        rs.getString("EVENT_NAME"), rs
                                .getString("COMPANY_NAME"), rs
                                .getString("EVENT_VENUE"), rs
                                .getString("EVENT_TIME"), rs
                                .getString("TOTAL_AMOUNT"), rs
                                .getString("RECEIVED_AMOUNT"), rs
                                .getString("CHEQUE_DD_NO"), rs
                                .getString("dateAsPayment"), rs
                                .getString("BALANCE_AMOUNT"), rs
                                .getString("EVENT_TDS")));

                eventIdList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_ID"));
                eventNameList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_NAME"));
                companyNameList.add(rs.getString("COMPANY_NAME"));
                eventVenueList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_VENUE"));
                eventTimeList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_TIME"));
                totalAmountList.add(rs.getString("TOTAL_AMOUNT"));
                receivedAmountList.add(rs.getString("RECEIVED_AMOUNT"));
                chequeDdList.add(rs.getString("CHEQUE_DD_NO"));
                paymentDateList.add(rs.getString("dateAsPayment"));
                eventTdsList.add(rs.getString("EVENT_TDS"));
                balanceAmountList.add(rs.getString("BALANCE_AMOUNT"));

            }
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventIdPdf", eventIdList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventNamePdf", eventNameList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("companyNamePdf", companyNameList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventVenuePdf", eventVenueList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventTimePdf", eventTimeList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("totalAmountPdf", totalAmountList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("receivedAmountPdf", receivedAmountList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("chequeDdPdf", chequeDdList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("paymentDatePdf", paymentDateList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("eventTdsPdf", eventTdsList);
            sessionMapGeneral.put("balanceAmountPdf", balanceAmountList);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }

        return SUCCESS;

    }

    public String generatePdfGeneral() throws Exception {

        System.out.println(sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf"));
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        float[] columnWidths = { 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("D:\\GeneralReports.pdf"));
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(11);
        table.setSpacingBefore(25);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setSpacingAfter(25);
        table.setWidths(columnWidths);
        PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event ID "));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event Name "));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event Time"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event Venue"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Company Name"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Amount"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Received Amount"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cheque/DD Number"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Payment Date"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Event TDS"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Balance Amount"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        table.setHeaderRows(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf");
        for (String item : list) {
            cell.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }
        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list1 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("eventNamePdf");
        for (String item : list1) {
            cell1.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }
        table.addCell(cell1);
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list2 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("eventTimePdf");
        for (String item : list2) {
            cell2.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }
        table.addCell(cell2);
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list3 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("eventVenuePdf");
        for (String item : list1) {
            cell3.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }

        table.addCell(cell3);
        PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list4 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf");
        for (String item : list4) {
            cell4.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }

        table.addCell(cell4);
        PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list5 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("companyNamePdf");
        for (String item : list5) {
            cell5.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }

        table.addCell(cell5);
        PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list6 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("totalAmountPdf");
        for (String item : list6) {
            cell6.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }

        table.addCell(cell6);
        PdfPCell cell7 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list7 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("receivedAmountPdf");
        for (String item : list7) {
            cell7.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }

        table.addCell(cell7);
        PdfPCell cell8 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list8 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("chequeDdPdf");
        for (String item : list8) {
            cell8.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }

        table.addCell(cell8);
        PdfPCell cell9 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list9 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("paymentDatePdf");
        for (String item : list9) {
            cell9.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }

        table.addCell(cell9);
        PdfPCell cell10 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list10 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("eventTdsPdf");
        for (String item : list10) {
            cell10.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }

        table.addCell(cell10);
        PdfPCell cell11 = new PdfPCell();
        List<String> list11 = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral
                .get("balanceAmountPdf");
        for (String item : list11) {
            cell11.addElement(new Paragraph(item));
        }

        table.addCell(cell11);

        document.open();
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
        return "success";

    }

    public String generateGeneralXls() throws Exception {
        try {
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");
            HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
            rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Event ID");
            rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Event Name");
            rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Event Time");
            rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Event Venue");
            rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("Company Name");
            rowhead.createCell(5).setCellValue("Total Amount");
            rowhead.createCell(6).setCellValue("Received Amount");
            rowhead.createCell(7).setCellValue("Payment Date");
            rowhead.createCell(8).setCellValue("Cheque/DD No.");
            rowhead.createCell(9).setCellValue("Event TDS");
            rowhead.createCell(10).setCellValue("Balance Amount");
            FileOutputStream fileOut;

            fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Samplmgjkm.xls");

            // HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow((short) 1);
            System.out.println(sessionMapGeneral.size());
            for (int i = 1; i <= sessionMapGeneral.size(); i++) {
                HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow((short) i);
                row1.createCell(i-1).setCellValue(
                        sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf").toString());

                row1.createCell(i).setCellValue(
                        sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());

            }


            /*
             * row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(
             * sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());
             * row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(
             * sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());
             * row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(
             * sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());
             * row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(
             * sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());
             * row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(
             * sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());
             * row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(
             * sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());
             * row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(
             * sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());
             * row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(
             * sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());
             * row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(
             * sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf").toString());
             */

            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sessionMapGeneral = (SessionMap) map;
    }

}
```

I have edited my code where I get result in string but all records are displayed in single cell. I want each record in new cell.I have attached image of how it looks.  [image]
No error is displayed. Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: anyone help me please :(

Comment: `createCell(2)` and 3, 4, 5, ...

Comment: can you show me your sessionMapGeneral class where you have maintain getter and setter methods for all variables ?

Comment: Yes,I have edited my code sir @Vickyexpert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First poposal** : use event object.You build a list of Event object you could use and put in SessionMap  and if you want, build the other list using list of Events)

here and Exemple assuming you have getter  in Event Object :

```
  public  String generateGeneralXls() throws Exception {
            try {
                
                String titles="Event ID,Event Name,Event Time,Event Venue,Company Name,Total Amount,Received Amount,Payment Date,Cheque/DD No,Event TDS,Balance Amount";
                String[]arrTiltes=titles.split(",");
                
                
                         

                
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("poi-test.xls");
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");

                
                int row=0;
                HSSFRow rowTitle = worksheet.createRow(row);
                
                // set  titles
                
                
                
                for(int i=0;i<arrTiltes.length;i++){
                    HSSFCell cellTitle=rowTitle.createCell(i);
                    cellTitle.setCellValue(arrTiltes[i]);
                    
                
                }
                
                //setting values
                row++;
                for(Event dataValue:dataForGeneralReports){
                    HSSFRow rowValue = worksheet.createRow(row);
                     
                    
                        HSSFCell cell0 = rowValue.createCell(0);
                        cell0.setCellValue(dataValue.getEventID());
                        
                        HSSFCell cell1 = rowValue.createCell(1);
                        cell1.setCellValue(dataValue.getEventName());
                        
                        HSSFCell cell2 = rowValue.createCell(2);
                        cell2.setCellValue(dataValue.getEventTime());
                        
                        HSSFCell cell3 = rowValue.createCell(3);
                        cell3.setCellValue(dataValue.getEventVenue());
                        
                        HSSFCell cell4 = rowValue.createCell(4);
                        cell4.setCellValue(dataValue.getCompanyName());
                        
                        HSSFCell cell5 = rowValue.createCell(5);
                        cell5.setCellValue(dataValue.getTotalAmount());
                        
                        HSSFCell cell6 = rowValue.createCell(6);
                        cell6.setCellValue(dataValue.getReceivedAmount());
                        
                        HSSFCell cell7 = rowValue.createCell(7);
                        cell7.setCellValue(dataValue.getPaymentDate());
                        
                        HSSFCell cell8 = rowValue.createCell(8);
                        cell8.setCellValue(dataValue.getChequeDDNo());

                        HSSFCell cell9 = rowValue.createCell(9);
                        cell9.setCellValue(dataValue.getEventTDS());
                        

                        HSSFCell cell10 = rowValue.createCell(10);
                        cell10.setCellValue(dataValue.getBalanceAmount());
                        
                        row++;                      
                    
                    
                }
                

        
                workbook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "success";
        }
```

you can use the same idea for you PDF.
be carreful in your code for PDF, i suspect you don't have results expected.

1. you have forgotten adding cell on table ( first cell on your code)
2. you have 12 cells however you declare 11:

   i sugest you o remove "block" for

> PdfPCell cell4

**second proposal** : if you want really use your lists, then iterate over each list to get first value in each of them, second value of each of them etc..

Exemple assuming all list have the same size (coming from your resultset):

```
public String generateGeneralXlsOther() throws Exception {
    try {
        
        String titles="eventIdPdf,eventNamePdf,companyNamePdf,eventVenuePdf,eventTimePdf,totalAmountPdf,receivedAmountPdf,receivedAmountPdf,chequeDdPdf,paymentDatePdf,eventTdsPdf,balanceAmountPdf";
            
        String[]arrTiltes=titles.split(",");        
              

        
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("poi-testOtehr.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");

        
        
        HSSFRow rowTitle = worksheet.createRow(0);
        
        // set  titles
        
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<arrTiltes.length;i++){
            HSSFCell cellTitle=rowTitle.createCell(i);
            cellTitle.setCellValue(arrTiltes[i]);
            
        
        }
        
        
         int size=((List<String>) sessionMapGeneral.get(arrTiltes[0])).size();
        for(int row=0;row<size;row++){
            
            
            HSSFRow rowValue = worksheet.createRow(row+1);
            int cell=0;
          for(int i=0;i<arrTiltes.length;i++){
              
              List<String> theList=(List<String>) sessionMapGeneral.get(arrTiltes[i]);
              HSSFCell cell0 = rowValue.createCell(cell);
                cell0.setCellValue(theList.get(row));
                cell++;
              
          }
        }
        

        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: it gives null pointer exception at              for(Event dataValue:dataForGeneralReports) this line

Comment: @Siddhesh Kalgaonkar put the dataForGeneralReports in sessionMapGeneral in execute() Method.as you did it for your lists.and get it (from sessionMapGeneral )  in the generateGeneralXls() method before iterate over it ( before the line you specified).

Comment: dataForGeneralReports = (List<Event>) sessionMapGeneral.get("dataforgeneral");
   I added this line and it worked ....Thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut;
fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Samplmgjkm.xls");

int nextRow = 1;

while(rs.next()){
   HSSFRow r = sheet.getRow(nextRow);
   if (r == null) {
       r = sheet.createRow(nextRow);
   }

   HSSFCell c = r.getCell(1, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
   c.setCellValue(rs.getString(1));

   HSSFCell c2 = r.getCell(2, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
   c2.setCellValue(rs.getString(2));

   nextRow++;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use rs.next in this method . I have fetched data in arraylist object in some another method an I have passed that list object in session and want to use session variable (which has data of string type) for creating dynamic records. So can you help me with the same ?

Comment: If you are having List then use a For Each instead of while loop

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and done some editing as below, so please refer below code and you will get solution.

```
 List<String> eventIdPdf = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf");

List<String> eventNamePdf = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf");


 for (int i = 1; i <= sessionMapGeneral.size(); i++) {
            HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow((short) i);
            row1.createCell(i-1).setCellValue(eventIdPdf.get(i).toString());

            row1.createCell(i).setCellValue(eventNamePdf.get(i).toString());

        }
```

As you are taking list of strings in one variable like eventIdPdf, so as per your use in code you are writing entire list in one cell therefor you are getting entire list in one cell, now check above method so it will display one by one answer.

Hope this will work..

Comment: Sorry to forget you to inform that may be your for loop will not work properly, you may need to take for(int i = 0; i < sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf").size(); i++)

Comment: thank you for your reply sir . I will try and will let you know

Comment: No sir ,it shows red line on setcellvalue method and also your second approach didn't worked.

Comment: you need to convert it first from object to string dear as below...

List<String> eventIdList = (List<String>) sessionMapGeneral.get("eventNamePdf"); 
and then use this event list check my edited answer

Comment: thank you sir for you answer it gives data in different rows but it gives in diagonal form not in one column .so how can i solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your **first problem** is here:

```
row1.createCell(i-1).setCellValue(
                        sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf").toString());
```

because `sessionMapGeneral.get("eventIdPdf").toString()` returns the whole eventIdList, or more precisely, all values of eventIdList as a String, so the result of this expression looks like 
"`[value1, value2, ... , valueN]`" 
and this (very long) result goes comletely to the `row1.createCell(i-1)`. But actually, `Cell(i-1)` should get only the `"value1"`. And here we go to 
your **second problem**:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sessionMapGeneral.size(); i++)
```

You iterate just through the `sessionMapGeneral`, but iterating through 2D-structures like tables or matrices requires two loops (nested loop). Notice, your `sessionMapGeneral's` elements are Key-Value pairs, where every Key is a String, e.g. `"eventIdPdf"`, and every Value is a List, e.g. `eventIdList`. So, in the first loop you should access the values (Lists) of the `sessionMapGeneral` to get to your data stored there. Then, in the second loop, you can iterate through the Lists you got in the first loop, in order to get every single data item and set it into the required cell of the table.
The next small problem is, you can't access `SessionMap's` elements by index, but there is a way to "beat the system" :) - here it is 
**your solution:** (please pay attention to comments)

```
//modify your key-Strings in order to be able to sort them later easily
        sessionMapGeneral.put("01_eventIdPdf", eventIdList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("02_eventNamePdf", eventNameList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("03_companyNamePdf", companyNameList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("04_eventVenuePdf", eventVenueList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("05_eventTimePdf", eventTimeList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("06_totalAmountPdf", totalAmountList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("07_receivedAmountPdf", receivedAmountList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("08_chequeDdPdf", chequeDdList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("09_paymentDatePdf", paymentDateList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("10_eventTdsPdf", eventTdsList);
        sessionMapGeneral.put("11_balanceAmountPdf", balanceAmountList);
```

...

```
fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Samplmgjkm.xls");

// get all the key-Strings from sessionMapGeneral and store them in an ArrayList in order to be able to access the elements by index
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(sessionMapGeneral.keySet()); 
// and sort them, so that they suit to your "rowhead"
Collections.sort(keys);

// iterate through the keys and fill out the xls table column by column:
for (int key = 0; key < keys.size(); key++) {
    //hold the current List from sessionMapGeneral for the current column in a variable
    List<String> currentList = (List<String>) (sessionMapGeneral.get(keys.get(key))); 
    // iterate through the current ArrayList (column) and fill out the cells of this column row by row:
    for (int row = 0; row < currentList.size(); row++) {
        // hold the current row in a variable
        HSSFRow currentRow = sheet.getRow(row+1);
        // create a row only once to avoid deleting the data set earlier and set the value into the cell
        if (currentRow == null) {
            currentRow = sheet.createRow((short) row+1); // I don't understand why do you cast it to short. To save 16 bit per row?
            currentRow.createCell(key).setCellValue(currentList.get(row));
        } else {
            currentRow.createCell(key).setCellValue(currentList.get(row));
        }
    }
// to make the width of columns looking well, add this line here:
sheet.autoSizeColumn(key);
}
```

Comment: it gives class cast exception at List<String> currentList = (List<String>) (sessionMapGeneral
      .get(keys.get(key))); this line

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar actually it shouldn't, it works for me. Here is a [screenshot](http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/8_6_2016/16/k8dA686rakOjNBhVOGI8Lw.png) of the result table filled with random data. _What_ can't be casted to _what_? Could you give me please the full exception message?